# Loop through range of cells checking for the letter X, shade adjacent cells in that row

Tags: vba, excel

I want to loop through a range of cells checking for the letter X. If there is an X I want to shade the cells in the column to the left and right of the cell with the X in the range. I have never used conditional formatting and looked at that, but I don't think that is going to work. I believe I am going to need .Offset, but I am not sure how to use it. Below is my code.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

Application.EnableEvents = False

If Not Application.Intersect(Target, Me.Range("D14:K19")) Is Nothing Then
    For Each Cell In Range("D14:K19")
        If ActiveCell.Value = "x" Or ActiveCell.Value = "X" Then
            ActiveCell.Offset(
        End If
    Next Cell
End If

Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Conditional formatting might work, for example with the Rule Formula `=OR(C14="X",E14="X")` applied to the range `=$D$14:$K$19`

Comment: Conditional Formatting will definitely work. No need for VBA for this (provided the requirements are as simple as you explain).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to assume you mean the column to the right/left rather than row. Things will be slightly different if you meant the row above/below.

To answer your question, `ActiveCell.Offset(0, -1)` will give you the cell to the left of the active one. ie the same column and 1 cell to the left (or more properly, -1 to the right...). In the same way, `ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1)` will give the cell to the right of the active one.

However, you'll want the replace each instance of `ActiveCell` with `Cell`, as that is what you are looping through.